# How to convert html tags and inline css when export to MS Word? [Still not resolve]

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, ms-word, ckeditor4.x, npoi

My project have some input to let user type in. And one of the input is textarea using ckeditor, as we know when using ckeditor we can let our input text be like change color or change the font size.

Like first, my text is "Hello" and I want it to be font size 20px, so the ckeditor source code will be `<span style="font-size:20px;">Hello</span>`

When I export to MS Word, it will display like `<span style="font-size:20px;">Hello</span>`

The problem is I don't want display like this. I want to display like only "Hello" and the font size is already 20px

How to convert html tag and inline css when exporting to MS Word?

I'm using ASP.NET and AngularJS  and NPOI to export to Word.

My question is that how to export ckeditor's text to Word through NPOI and keep the way like just paste from ckeditor to Word

Comment: Pasting from ckeditor into Word works fine for me. It's kind of one of their foundational features. Are you copying from the source view instead of the rich text view?

Comment: @JacobStamm I'm not copying from ckeditor to Word,   I'm using angularjs as frontend to get the data and pass to asp.net mvc controller, and then use NPOI to replace the template I already created, so the input text that using ckeditor would become like source view when export to MS Word.